# Linq: Removing Group By but still get its items?

Tags: c#, linq

Just some details. Get Records is a variable where it contains the results of my stored procedure. Now, what I want to ask is what if I want to remove the group by function but I still want to get the key and items? Is there a way to do it?

```
var sortResCinema = GetRecords.Where(x => test2.branch == x.Bbranch && test.movieName == x.MovieName && x.MovieName != null)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.MovieName,
                          (key, elements) =>
                           new
                           {
                               Id = key,
                               Items = elements.ToList()

                            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `GroupBy` here since you are looking for a specific movieName.

I guess you wanted something like this:

```
var sortResCinema = GetRecords.Where(x => test2.branch == x.Bbranch && test.movieName == x.MovieName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the GroupBy with a Select. The Select statement can be used to alter the type of the results returned, which is what you appear to want to do. Should work with exactly the same syntax as the second parameter.  So replace "GroupBy" with "Select" and remove the first argument.  The key and elements properties that are being used in the GroupBy statement are internal to that function so you'd need to work out what function you want to replace these by, for instance the key might be x.MovieName.

Comment: Can you show the actual code on how to do it? I'm still not familiar with Linq.

Comment: have updated my answer.  It's quite hard without knowing the exact structure of the objects that your stored procedure is returning.  I'm guessing that 'key' and 'elements' are properties of that object.

Comment: I already tried the code but it says that there is no extension method for key and elements. It's just that I still need the where function. But I still need to get the key and elements (which are some items to be found from there)

Comment: ok, so I misunderstood slightly before.  The key and elements properties are internal to the GroupBy command.  The key will in your case be the MovieName whilst the elements are all items which have this MovieName.  Removing the GroupBy doesn't make sense here.  If you don't want to group the elements then the use of a key wouldn't work as you could have multiple elements with the same key.

Comment: The second answer worked. I guess, I wasn't able to explain it well enough. I just want to get each result of the query so I guess it's true that the group by doesn't make sense anymore and I had to remove it and I just changed something from my code...